# Meu projeto no Unity 3D na parte dos LAYERS nao aparece a opção Shootable e Floor e mais algumas opções

Tags: unity3d

Olá, eu formatei o meu PC e fiz um backup do projeto. instalei o Windows 8.1 pro, instalei o **Unity 3D v 5.2**  coloquei meu projeto la tudo certinho ai quando fui dar play do projeto o personagem não olhava em direção a seta do mouse eu ja sabia que era problema no layer ai quando fui la para arrumar não tinha a opção que eu precisava, alguém pode me ajudar ?

estou fazendo o tutorial do *Unity Training Day*.
*Survivor Shooter Game*.

[image: opção LAYER]

[image: opção TAG]

Comment: O que acontece quando você tenta adicionar as opções que faltam? É só clicar no final do pop-up na opção edit layers e adicionar não é?